# How does refreshApex work alongside ImperativeApex

Tags: lightning-web-components

I used wiredApex to work alongside the update function coupled with refreshApex - it throws too many SOQL errors as expected. I changed the approach to imperative Apex but the refreshApex isn't working.

Please find the below code snippets:

**Apex** Class:

```java
public with sharing class CaseList {
    public CaseList() {

    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Case> getAllCases(){
        return [select Id, CaseNumber, Subject, Priority, Status from Case where Status != 'Closed'];
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static void updateStatus(String recordId){
        try {
            Case caseObj = new Case(Id = recordId);
            caseObj.Status = 'New';
            update caseObj;
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

**JS**:

```js
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import getAllCases from '@salesforce/apex/CaseList.getAllCases';
import updateStatus from '@salesforce/apex/CaseList.updateStatus';
import {refreshApex} from '@salesforce/apex';

const columns = [
    {label : 'Case Number', fieldName : 'CaseNumber', type : 'String'},
    {label : 'Case Subject', fieldName : 'Subject', type : 'String'},
    {label : 'Case Priority', fieldName : 'Priority', type : 'String'},
    {label : 'Case Status', fieldName : 'Status', type : 'String'},
]; 

export default class CaseList extends LightningElement {

    cols = columns;
    casesList = [];
    errorEnc   = [];
    selectedRecord;
    caseListFinal = [];

    connectedCallback(){

        getAllCases()
            .then(result => {
                this.casesList = result;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.errorEnc = error;
            })
    }

    handleRowAction(event){
        if(event.detail.selectedRows.length > 0){
            this.selectedRecord = event.detail.selectedRows[0].Id;
            alert(this.selectedRecord);
        } 
    }

    handleClick(){
        updateStatus({
            recordId : this.selectedRecord
        })
        .then(result => {
            alert('Success');
            refreshApex(this.casesList);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            alert('Error');
        })
    }
}
```

**HTML**:

```html
<template>
    <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
        <lightning-card  variant="Narrow"  title="Case Details" icon-name="standard:case">
            <lightning-datatable
                key-field="id"
                data={casesList}
                show-row-number-column
                columns={cols}
                onrowselection={handleRowAction}>
            </lightning-datatable>
            <br/>
            <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Update Status" title="updateStatus" onclick={handleClick}></lightning-button>
        </lightning-card>
    </div>
</template>
```

Any bright ideas here?

Answer (score 0):

Normally when you call refreshApex , the data provisioned by apex should be @wire .

The function refreshApex  provisions the data using the configuration bound to the @wire and updates the cache,

In your case it is an imperative Apex method and refreshApex won't work as your data is not cached.

For more on Apex method for LWC , click [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.apex_result_caching)